# Setting the organizer property in an iCalendar file (.ics)

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

We are generating ics files for events with the php library [ZContent/icalendar](https://github.com/ZContent/icalendar), so far, it works.

Nevertheless, when using the file with Google calendar, the event is displayed like this:

[image: google agenda entry]

How to set a value for "Unknown Organizer*"? (Qui) (Who)

When looking [at the specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar#Events_(VEVENT)), there is an `ORGANIZER` property, but it doesn't seem linked to events but to `VTODO` and `VJOURNAL` objects.

Or does it expects an email? Not only a name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well the actual specification for VEVENT is at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1 and it certainly does include the organiser property which itself has a mailto: uri as value and usually also has a CN parameter. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.3

which gives a basic example:

```
ORGANIZER;CN=John Smith:mailto:jsmith@example.com
```